# How to get variable of different script file which already exists in my script file?

Tags: bash

My intention was to use variables of other script files from my current script file.

I am doing this using `source`

For example,

I have two files, `test.sh` and `test1.sh`

In `test.sh`, i have:

```
hello="hello world"
```

In `test1.sh`, i am doing this:

```
source test.sh
echo "$hello"
```

But what if i have a variable named `hello` in `test1`?

Well i have found that, if i `source` after the variable declaration like this:

```
hello= "Good bye world"
source test.sh
echo "$hello"
```

I will get,

```
hello world
```

But if do,

```
 source test.sh 
 hello= "Good bye world"
 echo "$hello"
```

I will get,

```
 Good bye world
```

To me, this is very inconvenient for me, as i have to look after where i am using `source` and may be need to do it again and again if I want to switch between these two variables.

How to resolve this?

For example, i want to do something like this,

```
echo $hello(of the localone) $hello(of the sourced one)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, where are you performing "source test1.sh"? Is it in another file like test2.sh?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque - when you `source` any file, you are inserting the contents of that file at the point where the call to `source` is made. Just like positioning your cursor on the line and choosing `File->Insert->File test1.sh` in most editors. So if any variable exists prior to the line where `source` is called, it is simply *reassigned* the value in `test1.sh`.

Comment: @shanmuga, if you are sure about it, you can post it as an answer a little bit elaborately. I will accept the answer.

Comment: @rici I stand corrected, i'll delete my previous comment.  bash `source test.sh` is equivalent to `. ./test.sh` in dash and other shell. [As mentioned here](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html). However I still don't see any mechanism in shell to avoid namespace collision as requested by OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO** it is not possible.
Shell doesn't provide any mechanism to handle namespace collision for variables.

*Note*: korn-shell does provide a command **(not part of POSIX, not supported by others)**  `namespace` to handle this particular problem. This is explained in this [question at unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213980/shell-namespaces)

```
echo 'function hi { echo Ahoj, světe\!;  }' >  czech.ksh
echo 'function hi { echo Hello, World\!; }' >english.ksh
namespace english { . ./english.ksh; }
namespace czech   { . ./czech.ksh;   }
.english.hi; .czech.hi
```

This behavior is mentioned here in this [comparison of different unix shells](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells)
and this old [bash FAQ](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2002-01/msg00068.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `source test.sh`, it is like copy-pasting the entire test.sh into and executing it.

So doing

```
hello= "Good bye world"
source test.sh
echo "$hello"`
```

Is equivalent to

```
hello= "Good bye world"
hello="hello world"
echo "$hello"
```

And doing

```
source test.sh 
hello= "Good bye world"
echo "$hello"
```

is equivalent to

```
hello="hello world"
hello= "Good bye world"
echo "$hello"
```

In both cases, the value of `hello` is being specified twice. The second value overrides the first value.

Your best option is to use different variable names in your files, e.g. `hello` in test.sh and `hello1` in test1.sh

Comment: Your answer could have been a bit more concise from a choice of words standpoint, but it hit all the relevant points. I think explaining that "`source` inserts the referenced script verbatim at the point the call to `source` is made" is exactly what you meant by copy-paste...